# Regex for valid SSN or other ID

Tags: regex

I'm a regex newbie and I've got a valid regex for SSNs:

```
/^(\d{3}(\s|-)?\d{2}(\s|-)?\d{4})|[\d{9}]*$/
```

But I now need to expand it to accept either an SSN or another alphanumeric ID of 7 characters, like this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$/
```

I thought it'd be as simple as grouping the SSN and adding  an OR | but my tests are still failing. This is what I've got now:

```
/^((\d{3}(\s|-)?\d{2}(\s|-)?\d{4})|[\d{9}])|[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$/
```

What am I doing wrong? And is there a more elegant way to say either SSN or my other ID?

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Valid SSNs:

- 123-45-6789
- 123456789
- 123 45 6789

Valid ID: aCe8999

Comment: It should be `^RE1$|^RE2$` or `^(RE1|RE2)$`

Comment: Also there are major problems with your first regex. Please put it away.

Comment: can you please add your SNN and ID example not everyone know the format of that considering people from other countries, so everyone can help

Comment: |[\d{9}]* in your first regex is just wrong. Get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your first regex also a bit, below is demo program. This is as per my understanding of the problem. Let me know if any modification is needed.

```
my @ids = (
    '123-45-6789',
    '123456789',
    '123 45 6789',
    '1234567893434',  # invalid
    '123456789wwsd',  # invalid
    'aCe8999',
    'aCe8999asa' # invalid
);

for (@ids) {
    say "match = $&" if $_ =~ /^ (?:\d{3} ([ \-])? \d{2} \1? \d{4})$ | ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$/x ;
}
```

Output:

```
match = 123-45-6789
match = 123456789
match = 123 45 6789
match = aCe8999
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first regex got some problems. The important thing about it is that it accepts `{{{{}}}}}` which means you have built a wrong character class. Also it matches `123-45 6789` (notice the mixture of space and dash).

To mean OR in regular expressions you need to use pipe `|` and remember that each symbol belongs to the side that it resides. So for example `^1|2$` checks for strings beginning with `1` or ending with `2` not only two individual input strings `1` and `2`.

To apply the exact match you need to do `^1$|^2$` or `^(1|2)$`.

With the second regex `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$` you are not saying *alphanumeric ID of 7 characters* but you are saying numeric, alphabetic or alphanumeric. So it matches `1234567` too. If this is not a problem, the following regex is the solution by eliminating the said issues:

```
^\d{3}([ -]?)\d\d\1\d{4}$|^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issue with the 2nd regex not really testing for alphanumeric characters.